# IBM dashDb stop_on_error blocker

Tags: database

I am trying to call POST request POST /sql_jobs (dashdbAPI_v2), but I can’t figure out what should be in stop_on_error. It requires string and always ends with error "Parameter stop_on_error is required".

Could you help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only valid values for `stop_on_error` are `yes` and `no`. If the value doesn't match one of them, it returns the error message you're seeing.

This is a working sample:

```
curl \
  -X POST "https://host.bluemix.net/dashdb-api/v2/sql_jobs" \
  -H "accept: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzA ..." \
  -H "content-type: application/json" \
  -d '{ "commands": "SELECT 1", "limit": 0, "stop_on_error": "yes", "separator": ";" }'
```